# Importing a jar into android

Tags: java, android, jar, package

I'm trying to import a jar named Security.jar into an Android app that I'm currently working on, however, no matter what I do I cannot get AS to recognize the package that I'm importing. I pasted the jar into the libs folder that I created for the app and synced the gradle files, as well as modified the dependancies, all to no avail. If anyone sees ANYTHING that's wrong please let me know! Here's a link to some pictures pertaining to the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6oQX.jpg

[error log build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljocQ.png)

Comment: Please copy your code into the question instead of posting screen shots.  It makes it easier to read and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should do this:

```
compile files('libs/your.api.jar')
```

When you've pasted the jar file in the `libs` folder. Give it a shot.

Comment: Please view the image I added to the post. It shows the error I'm receiving as well as my build.gradle file. Thanx! I added what you suggested to the dependencies to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to add external JARs to your Android project or any Java project is:

right click on your project ..
then goto properties..
then click on java build path..
then click on libraries...
then click on add External JARs..
select jar file ..
click on ok